# Difference between these two ( usage of "using")

Tags: .net

What is the difference between these two ?

```
// Get response  
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)  
{  
    // Get the response stream  
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());  

    // Console application output  
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());  
}
```

without using*

```
// Get response  
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse; 

// Get the response stream  
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());  

// Console application output  
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Using` requires that the object applied to it implement `IDisposable`, and will call the `Dispose` method of `IDisposable` when the object goes out of scope of the `using` block (no matter how it leaves that scope... either by execution flowing through normally, or if an `Exception` is thrown).

The other variant is bad practice... your resources related to `response` will not be cleaned up.

Note that the `StreamReader` is not being cleaned up in either case.  You should use an inner `using` block to accomplish that.

Comment: reader.Dispose() also closes the stream that was passed in the constructor.  Be aware of it if you plan to keep stream open for any further work.

Answer (score 2):

With the first syntax `response.Dispose()` is called automatically at the end of the block.
To include an object in a `using` block it must implement `IDisposable` interface.
Use `using` when you can, so you're sure you don't forget to release allocated objects.